# Some site logos and favicons aren't displayed in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, images, logo

Some site logos and favicons aren't displayed in StackExchange Data Explorer (see screenshots below). The URLs of missing images, e.g. http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png, give server errors "404 - File or directory not found".

[Main page:](http://odata.stackexchange.com)

[image: Main page]

[Query page:](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/94/my-comments)

[image: Main page]

Comment: They must not like abbreviations anymore, http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png works :P

Comment: Ill sort this out soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a side effect of moving sstatic to NYC, fixed now

Comment: The logos work, but the little favicons (lower right of the screenshot above) still don't.

Comment: The problem still persists for Writing Stack Exchange, should I post this as a question?