# Dead images in SEDE homepage

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, 404-not-found

http://odata.stackexchange.com/ contains dead images pointing to http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png
[image: derp]

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69259/some-site-logos-and-favicons-arent-displayed-in-data-explorer

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the images for the trilogy on sstatic moved and the odata DB site table needs updating:

- http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png -> http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png
- http://sstatic.net/su/img/logo.png -> http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/logo.png
- http://sstatic.net/sf/img/logo.png -> http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/logo.png
- http://sstatic.net/mso/img/logo.png -> http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/logo.png

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69368/all-css-in-open-source-ads-is-broken and http://stackapps.com/questions/1754/api-helps-css-is-missing